# How to exclude persistence.xml from src/main/resources when running test cases? [Maven: Multi-Module]

Tags: unit-testing, maven, maven-3

I have a Maven based multi-module project. The project is an `EAR` file containing sub deployments including `first-ejb.jar` and `first-web.war`. The `first-ejb.jar` contains two `persistence.xml` one its `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` and the second one is in `src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`. The test cases of `first-ejb.jar` executes successfully where it picks `persistence.xml` from the test directory (i manually exclude `persistence.xml` from `main`). But when I run test cases for `first-web.war` it includes `persistence.xml` from the main directory of `first-ejb.jar` which fails my test cases.

So, my question is how to say in Maven in a multi-module project to include `persistence.xml` from test directory in `first-ejb.jar` when running test cases for `first-web.war` module.

EDIT:

So, I went through the classpath that is being used when tests of `first-web.war` are run. I see that it contains `first-ejb.jar` as its dependency (which is correct for production build). This in fact is screwing up tests for the `first-web.war` module as it ends up using `persistence.xml` from `src\main\resources` of `first-ejb.jar` module.

So, I believe what I need to do is declare another artifact which contains everything that `first-ejb.jar` contains but a different `persistence.xml` in its `src\main\resources` directory. I could name it `first-ejb-test.jar`. Then I can make this artifact a dependency of `first-web.war` project for running tests through `maven` profiles.

Comment: I have no authoritative answer, so I'll stick to a comment. But I don't think you can do this. I've had similar issues with application context files, and always ending up calling them differently when to be used during test (e.g. `beans.xml` vs. `test-beans.xml`). Not sure if the same approach would work for `persistence.xml`.

Comment: How do you run your tests which are indeed integration tests. Can you show the pom files?

Comment: @khmarbaise unfortunately i can't show my pom files but I have edited my question with some discoveries i found. And i believe it may not be possible what i orginally asked. The workaround or may be the correct way is to have another artifact which contains test specific stuff and make it a dependency whoever needs to use it. Please let me know if you have any suggestions. Cheers and thank you all for your time.